# Splitting integers and string from a value

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a list which include both integers and strings in every value. I want to make a list of values with only integers. ie.;

```
list = [u'1.0.365-SNAPSHOT', u'1.0.366-SNAPSHOT', u'1.0.367-SNAPSHOT', u'1.0.368-SNAPSHOT', u'1.0.369-SNAPSHOT', u'1.0.370-SNAPSHOT', u'1.0.372-SNAPSHOT', u'1.0.373-SNAPSHOT']
```

I would like to have list of values which should look like

```
list = [u'1.0.365', u'1.0.366', u'1.0.367', u'1.0.368', u'1.0.369', u'1.0.370', u'1.0.372', u'1.0.373']
```

I have been trying to use various functions such as `spilt()`. But was unable to get the desired result.

Comment: You say you want want integers, but the output you give is still strings. In fact, the u in `u'1.0.366'` is for 'unicode'. If you mean you want the half of the strings before the dash, use split with dash as the delimiter. If you post example code for what you've tried, you'll have a better question too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all values in the list end with `"-SNAPSHOT"`:

```
lst = [u'1.0.365-SNAPSHOT', u'1.0.366-SNAPSHOT', u'1.0.367-SNAPSHOT', u'1.0.368-SNAPSHOT', u'1.0.369-SNAPSHOT', u'1.0.370-SNAPSHOT', u'1.0.372-SNAPSHOT', u'1.0.373-SNAPSHOT']
lst2 = [x[:-9] for x in lst]
```

Try to avoid naming lists `list`. It will override the built-in type.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
for file_name in list:
   file_name = file_name.split('-')[0]
```